# Store variable when package is attached using .onAttach

Tags: r

I would like to store a value of variable in environment of my package when package is loaded. This is my current version, but I cannot see/access `my_var` after `library(mypkg)`:

```
.onAttach <- function(libname = find.package("mypkg"), pkgname = "mypkg") {
  message('on attach is called')
  my_var <- my_func()
  environment(my_var) <- as.environment("package:mypkg")
}

my_func <- function() {
  # Do something complicated here and return complex list.
  # Returning TRUE just to make it simple
  TRUE
}
```

Note that `my_var` is calculated using another function in my package called `my_func`

Comment: See eg [this file](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rpushbullet/blob/master/R/init.R) for a working solution.  I create the environment first outside of `.onAttach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol only lives within the scope of that function. Changing the environments does not reassign in a different scope. And `my_var` is just a "regular" variable, and variables do not have `environments()` (only functions and formulas, and maybe others, but not all variables). For example the built in `letters` variable comes from base but `environment(letters)` returns NULL.

If you want to assign a variable that will exist outside your function in a specific namespace, you should use `assign()`

```
.onAttach <- function(libname = find.package("mypkg"), pkgname = "mypkg") {
  message('on attach is called')
  my_var <- my_func()
  assign("my_var", my_var, envir=as.environment("package:mypkg"))
}
```